# org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I just tried out setting up a demo CRUD api in hibernate and I've been unable to resolve the issue with this. I've tried this with multiple versions of Hibernate but none seem to work. I keep getting the error message "Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel#id] : com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel@1bc31512",
"path": "/create/user", but everything seems fine. Here's the code for it:

FirstWebApp.java

```
package com.webapp.firstwebapp;

import java.io.File;
import com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class FirstwebappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FirstwebappApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/create/user")
    public UserModel doSomething() throws Exception{
        File file = new File("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        UserModel userModel = new UserModel(122, "Jane Doe", "jane_doe");

        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure(file).build();

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).addAnnotatedClass(UserModel.class).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        try{
            session.save(userModel);
            transaction.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
            throw e;
        }
        return userModel;
    }

}
```

UserModel.java

```
package com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class UserModel {  

    
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public Integer id;
    
    @Column(name="name", nullable = false, unique = false)
    public String name;

    @Column(name="username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String username;

    // @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")

    public UserModel(){
            
    }

    public UserModel(Integer id, String name, String username){
        this.id = id;
        this.username= username;
        this.name = name;
        
    }

    public void setId(Integer id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }
    
}
```

Is there something I'm missing or am I doing something wrong? Here is the full log report I'm getting on the console:

```
ERROR 11976 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel#id] : com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel@1bc31512] with root cause    

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel.id to com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) 
~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:418) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5150) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:179) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:637) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:630) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:625) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
        at com.webapp.firstwebapp.FirstwebappApplication.doSomething(FirstwebappApplication.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:802) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) 
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2020-09-06 19:00:23.731  INFO 11976 --- [       Thread-5] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Comment: Try to create getters and setters for the all fields of the `UserModel` entity.

Comment: I did. I'm still getting the same error message. I also tried setting the access type to PROPERTY rather than FIELD. Then it says, can't access getter for the property id.

Answer (score 0):

AS the error says `"Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel.id]`

This is related to the scope for the attributes of `UserModel` entity

You have to make public access modifiers for attributes of `UserModel` Entity

Comment: I made everything public. I'm still getting the same error message. I even directly followed an online tutorial, doing exactly what they did and it's still the same. I used the same hibernate version and everything available in the source file. I've tried using different techniques but it is still the same thing everytime.

Comment: Sure. This I've updated the question with the new UserModel class

Comment: I have. You can check again. I made the private fields public and added the getters and setters for each field

Comment: The exception message is still the same as before. Although, the ,message I'm getting from Postman is _"org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel#id] : com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel@3d0e29af"_

Comment: It can't be as the exception says Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel.id] and there is no private id field in UserModel ... Seems some code update issue

Comment: For some reason, it is. I tried it on Insomnia and it says _"org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel#id] : com.webapp.firstwebapp.Models.UserModel@3d0e29af"_

Comment: How are you  executing this code ... what steps are you following

Comment: I run it as I would for a normal java app directly from the code editor. Once the server starts up, I try making the GET request to the url and then this happens

Comment: Seems the class files are not getting updated... you can confirm it by changing the "id" attribute to some other name and then check the exception ... if this is still the case  then you need to clean the project

Comment: Wow. Just did and it's still not working. I also tried creating a fresh project from scratch and still getting the same error