# Unable to add value to entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I can’t set the discipline values ​​​​for my semester, when I work out the controller, I get all the data I need, but I can’t connect them, can anyone tell me with an experienced eye what is the reason? I am getting this kind of error:

Request processing failed; nested exception is

> org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private int com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity.Discipline.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity.Discipline#id] : Higher mathematics

Here is my entity Semestr:

```java
package com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "semestr")
public class Semestr {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "duration")
    private String duration;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private boolean status = true;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "semestr_discipline",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_semestr"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_discipline")
    )
    private List<Discipline> disciplineList;


    public void addDisciplineToSemester(Discipline discipline) {
        if (disciplineList == null) {
            disciplineList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        disciplineList.add(discipline);
    }

    public Semestr() {
    }

    public Semestr(int id, String name, String duration, boolean status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Discipline> getDisciplineList() {
        return disciplineList;
    }

    public void setDisciplineList(List<Discipline> disciplineList) {
        this.disciplineList = disciplineList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Semestr semestr = (Semestr) o;

        if (id != semestr.id) return false;
        if (status != semestr.status) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(semestr.name) : semestr.name != null) return false;
        return duration != null ? duration.equals(semestr.duration) : semestr.duration == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (duration != null ? duration.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (status ? 1 : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Semestr{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", duration='" + duration + '\'' +
                ", status=" + status +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Controller :

```java
@RequestMapping("/saveNewSemester")
public String saveNewSemester(@ModelAttribute("semestr") Semestr semestr,
                              @RequestParam(name = "AllDiscipline") String[] AllDiscipline,
                              Model model) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(AllDiscipline).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Discipline> disciplineSemestrList = service.getDisciplineList(list);
    semestr.setDisciplineList(disciplineSemestrList);
    service.saveNewSemester(semestr);
    return "redirect:/semestr";
}
```

Here is my entity Discipline :

```java
package com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;


@Entity
@Table(name = "discipline")
public class Discipline {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "discipline")
    private String discipline;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private boolean status = true;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "semestr_discipline",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_discipline"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_semestr")
    )
    private List<Semestr> semestrList;

    public void addSemesterToDiscipline(Semestr semestr) {
        if (semestrList == null) {
            semestrList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        semestrList.add(semestr);
    }

    public Discipline() {

    }


    public Discipline(int id, String discipline, boolean status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.discipline = discipline;
        this.status = status;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDiscipline() {
        return discipline;
    }

    public void setDiscipline(String discipline) {
        this.discipline = discipline;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Semestr> getSemestrList() {
        return semestrList;
    }

    public void setSemestrList(List<Semestr> semestrList) {
        this.semestrList = semestrList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Discipline that = (Discipline) o;
        return id == that.id &&
                status == that.status &&
                Objects.equals(discipline, that.discipline);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, discipline, status);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Discipline{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", discipline='" + discipline + '\'' +
                ", status=" + status +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63767345/org-hibernate-property-access-spi-propertyaccessexception-error-accessing-field 
Take a look at the answer comments

Comment: Maybe debug at the line you are getting at exception at, and see if (id) is the same type it should be.

Comment: the solution was found, there was a problem that the data type in one column of the table of disciplines and the semester was enum , but in essence the boolean data type was registered, changing them to the correct ones, the addition succeeded